# AngularJS routing issue in .net core

Tags: angularjs, asp.net-core

I have added an angularJS app to a .net core mvc application within wwwroot.

Inside wwwroot I have added an App folder so I have this structure..
[image]

My BookingApp.ts module is pretty simple and looks like this - I am not doing anything with ngRoute at this stage..

```
var app = angular.module("BookingApp", ["ngRoute"]);
```

My CreateBookingController.ts looks like this

```
module BookingApp {
export class CreateBookingController {
    static $inject = ["$scope", "$http"];

    bookingData: IBookingViewModel;

    constructor($scope, $http) {            
    }

    static routing($routeProvider) {

        $routeProvider.when("createbooking",
            {
                controller: "CreateBookingController",
                templateUrl: "/App/CreateBooking/CreateBooking.html",
                controllerAs: "ctr"
                //medadata:{title:"",description:"",keywords:""}
            });
    }
}
angular.module("BookingApp")
    .controller("CreateBookingController", CreateBookingController)
    .config(["$routeProvider", CreateBookingController.routing]);
```

};

But when I got to "CreateBooking" in the url I get a 404 not found..

So I need to configure something in startup.cs for .net core?
It just has the usual stuff except in the Configure method there is

```
app.UseHttpsRedirection();
```

But I dont think that would cause an issue.
Thanks

Comment: Isn't the file supposed to be index.html?

Comment: Index is a default home page, but this is a more specific page not a home page.

Comment: I Think i need a catch all route for angular and then a cshtml view with ng-view on it. i will test this tomorrow and answer the question myself if it works,

Comment: Don't you need the leading `/` on your route definition? e.g. `$routeProvider.when("/createbooking", [...]);` It's also case-sensitive so `createbooking` is different than `CreateBooking`.

Comment: that is right, it should have the forward slash but the issue is MVC routing, i need a catch all. Watch this space!